# What's the reason of using Thread.Sleep in multi-threaded applications?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, sleep

Often times I when I see some multi-threaded code, I see `Thread.Sleep()` statements in the code.

I even had a crash where I was trying to figure out the problem, so commented out most of the multi-threaded code and slowly brought it and for the final piece when I added a for statement like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
    ++i;
```

it didn't crash. So now I replaced it `Thread.Sleep()` and it seems to work. I can't repro it easily to post it here, but is using `Thread.Sleep()` necessary for multi-threaded applications?

What's the purpose of them? Would it lead to unexpected results if not used?

EDIT: Btw I am using the `BackgroundWorker` and only implementing my stuff in there, but not sure what causes this. Although I am using an API which is the hosting app where the app is not multi threaded. So for instance I think I can't call it's API functions on several threads at once. Not sure, but that was my guess.

Comment: See [Thread.Sleep is a sign of a poorly designed program](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, `Thread.Sleep` is a sign of a bad design.  That being said, its MUCH better than eating 100% of the CPU core time, which is what the for loop above is doing.

A better option is typically to use a `WaitHandle`, such as a `ManualResetEvent`, to trigger the continuation of the thread's execution when the "event" (which is the reason to delay) occurs.  Alternatively, using a `Timer` can work as well in many cases.

Comment: Thanks Reed, can you do these with the BackgroundWorker?

Comment: @Joan: WaitHandles work fine with BW - BW is still just using a ThreadPool thread to do it's work, so any synchronization option still works.

Comment: Thanks Reed, that makes sense. But ultimately this delay can't be avoided, right?

Comment: @Joan: It depends - why are you introducing a delay in the first place?  Typically, it's because the algorithm is waiting for something external to happen.  If that's the case, that "external" thing can set a WaitHandle, and you can wait on it.  If that's not the case, then just take it out ;)

Comment: Thanks Reed, I am not sure either. Will investigate.

Comment: @Reed. Why is that using Thread.sleep() considered as bad design? Can you please share the details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sandeep: It's usually (not always, but usually) a workaround.  If you want to delay, it's typically to "wait for some other thing to happen" - by using a WaitHandle, you can signal exactly when that other thing happens, and only wait that exact amount of time.  If you want to trigger something at a time, then a Timer is a better option.

Answer (score 3):

The `Thread.Sleep(1)` allows switch to execution another thread. So if you have more threads than cores/processors and you know "now I did in this thread a lot of work and next work can be done little-bit later" you call `Thread.Sleep(1)` and allows another thread to do some work sooner than the native switcher will "pause" the currently executed thread.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(0)` should have the same effect without blocking for a whole ms.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  Write a program that launches 100 threads, and put each of the thread into a `for` loop as you described.  And then write another that launches 100 threads and uses `Thread.Sleep` instead.

Run them both and compare the CPU usage.  You'll see the point. =)

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep()` simply causes the executing thread to halt for the specified duration.

I've seen many developers use `Thread.Sleep()` because they don't probably handle the joining of dependent threads. They simply use `Thread.Sleep()` to force a thread to wait for some amount of time until the think their other threads would have finished and have their data available.

If you have two threads that need to wait on each other to proceed with their processing, you should really use the mechanisms built in to .NET that are meant to handle situations like that (ie. `ManualResetEvent`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep()` is OK to use in some situations eg. watchdog threads.

However in your case, it may not seem to be the optimal solution as pointed out by others.

Without a code sample, it's hard to tell, but based on your description, I don't think it's a question of `Thread.Sleep()` or not. I would suspect that you may be suffering from a race condition - that's usually why you experience "random" buggy behavior or even "random" crashes in multithreaded code - as seems to be what you are experiencing.

For whatever reason, your for-loop may cause the subtle critical timings of the race condition to occur less often, but it won't solve the root cause. There are many pitfalls to be aware of when doing multithreaded programming, I can only advice you to read up on the topic if you want to be able to avoid these.

I'll recommend reading [http://www.amazon.com/Concurrent-Programming-Windows-Joe-Duffy/dp/032143482X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X)